# Python on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pi-2

For my High School final project I will do a portable retro arcade machine. I think Raspberry Pi is a candidate for this application, and I've done some research on it. However, I've not been able to find an answer to this question: "Do all the raspberry pis come with Python, or will I need to install it?" (If it helps, I'll probably be using the raspberry pi 2 model b).

Thanks for the time spend and sorry if this question a "newbie one", appreciated guys.

Comment: Do you have a Pi?

Comment: Right now don't have any, never used one either

Comment: Depends on the Operating System you install. The most prolific is Raspbian and comes with Python pre-installed. Do you perhaps know what OS you will be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is included with the `Raspbian` distribution, and you won't need to install it separately. There are two versions of Python that are in current use, and both are included with Raspbian. The Raspberry Pi Organization has an [introductory page for new Python users that you should read as it explains some of the basics.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/python/)

Answer (score 2):

It will depend which operating system you choose, a common one for first go is Raspbian.

[Rasspberrypi.org/downloads](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/)

These both have python 2.7 and 3.2(?) version included.
Have fun!

Comment: Ah, yep. Changed.